# IntelliJ IDEA shows deleted files and packages in code completion

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, code-completion

I have changed the structure of the packages of my project. I have created new packages, moved some files into the new packages and deleted the empty packages where the files had been.

Now the problem is that the code completion shows some of the files twice, there is the new correct version and the old version with the old package structure.
Let me give to examples:

1. I had a class (file) "ButtonBuilder" in the package "component.builders.gui". Then I moved the "ButtonBuilder" into the package "component.builders.gui.button". When I now type somewhere "ButtonBuilder" the code completion suggests two versions, the first one is "ButtonBuilder (component.builders.gui)" and the second is "ButtonBuilder  component.builders.gui.button)", but there is no file / class named "ButtonBuilder" in "component.builders.gui".
2. The second example is similar, when I type "DefaultPhysicComponent" the code completion gives two options, "DefaultPhysicComponent (component.components.physic)" and "DefaultPhysicComponent (components.physicComponents)". The first one is correct but the second does not exist. The class / file "DefaultPhysicComponent" was at first in "components.physicComponents", then I created the new packages "component.components.physic", moved the file there and deleted the old packages. Now there does not even exist a package "physicComponents", but the code completion gives these two options.

There are also other files and packages with the same problem. So somehow the IDE "thinks" that the old packages and files still exists. This also yields another problem with the imports. When I import for example

import component.builders.gui.button.*;

and

import component.builders.gui.*;

the IDE says that the reference to "ButtonBuilder" is ambiguous, but as said above there exists only one file / class "ButtonBuilder".

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under `File > Preferences > Compiler` check that this option: "Clear output directory on rebuild" is selected.

Then rebuild your project using `Build > Rebuild Project`

If the problem is still occurring after that then invalidate caches, using `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart` then click on the `Invalidate` button.

Comment: I am using Android Studio 2.3.3 and I found the option "Clear output directory on rebuild" under File > Other Settings > Default Settings... > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler. After the rebuild it works now correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In order to delete non-existing files (but still detected as unresolved) you could try the following solution via mercurial:

hg resolve -all [verify the files detected as unresolved (the ones marked by U)]
Then for each unresolved and non-existing file execute 
hg resolve filepath  (+ choose "d" to delete it)